# met the same value when using the vlookup function

Tags: excel

I am having a problem as follows. I use the `vlookup()` function to get the value from table 1 through table 2. In table one there is a cell with a match value of March 29. Now is there any way that after using the `vlookup()` function, the value 400 and 500 in table 1 through table 2 becomes 900. Look forward to the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP()` will always lookup a value to a table and return first matching corresponding row of another column. You can use `SUMIFS()`. Try-

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,D$1)
```

[image]